# How do I use an IEndpointFilter on just certain methods?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I've implemented an `IEndpointFilter` in my ASP.Net Core application. When I call

```cs
app.MapControllers()
    .AddEndpointFilter(new AmpersandEndpointFilter());
```

That's going to map the filter to every single route. How do I apply it to just specific routes or, worst-case, a specific controller?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) .

Comment: @QingGuo Not sure what you want me to look at.  All of those are examples that don't use a controller.  The only controller related example, at the very bottom of the page, doesn't allow for any sort of specification as to which methods use the filter.